# AngularJS ng-repeat removing items to reclaim memory

Tags: angularjs, performance, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have added 20*10 items at a time to ng-repeat and remove 20*10 items at a time to reclaim memory space but I am not seeing memory reclaiming after nodes are removed. Why is memory not reclaimed? Am I doing something wrong?

[myPlunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mfccjJnfa2ZYYq8pHJjc?p=preview)

```
 angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
$scope.items =      ["http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs42/f/2009/073/e/d/Free_red_panda_icon_100x100_by_SuperTuffPinkPuff.png"];

$scope.remove = function(item) {
    console.log($scope.items.length)
    for(var a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
      $scope.items.shift($scope.items.length-1);
    }
};

$scope.add = function(item) {
    for(var a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
       $scope.items.push(item='http://fc06.deviantart.net/fs42/f/2009/073/e/d/Free_red_panda_icon_100x100_by_SuperTuffPinkPuff.png'); 
    }

};

});
```

update - I was using single FireFox and Chrome instance and the same thing happened. Meaning memory was not reclaimed in Task Manager. However, the browser Profiler is reclaimed, why?

[This guy](http://eol.dannysu.com/) was able to reclaim memory back after removing DOM nodes and I don't know why because I am doing the same.

Comment: http://embed.plnkr.co/yLuV8f1RGfKxWTHSMnQQ/preview , taking a snapshot on the Chrome profiler you can see that it starts at almost 23 Mb, then adding 10,000 get it to 50 Mb and after removing all the references it gets back to 23 Mb, what is the problem?

Comment: I wasnt using the profiler but Windows task manager using Firefox and I saw memory for Firefox claim 500,000kb and after I removed everything I added never got removed. So what is the difference between the two.

Comment: You are right, FF GC is pretty slow, I've been testing it and the memory recovery has some kind of delay. I bet is not related to Angular, is just the way FF works, let's see if there is any guru on the subject to enlighten us.

Comment: I have also tried this in Chrome the memory still does not get reclaimed. How I started on this path is reading this [article](http://engineering.linkedin.com/linkedin-ipad-5-techniques-smooth-infinite-scrolling-html5) by LinkedIn saying they were able to do it by removing DOM elements. Tried doing this with straight JavaScript and memory is not reclaimed for me. Also, found a guy who is able to do it [here](http://eol.dannysu.com/eol.js). Reviewing his code, he is just removing DOM elements and memory is reclaimed which works for him. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Claude Are you still measuring memory usage through the Windows Task manager? If you are doing so this is likely going to give you some issues as many other things can come into play. The Chrome profiler will show you what is actually happening for the specific page you want to analyze.

Comment: @mschuett Yes, I know the profiler shows something different. But, what is the difference and why. My Testing opens FireFox no other tabs. It's the only one in Task Manager, hit the page and test. If I do the same on [at this website, it works](http://eol.dannysu.com/), why?

Comment: See this is a more interesting question. However you should update your question to correspond with what you are actually looking for. I'm on a mac right now.. I'll mess around and see if i can reproduce the results you are getting with the windows task manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the reason memory was still being held. When you use shift to remove an item from an array it returns that item which you have removed so you have to set it to null. Which I was not doing.

```
$scope.remove = function(item) {

 for(var a = 0; a < 20; a++) {
   var removedItem = $scope.items.shift($scope.items.length-1);
   removedItem = null;
 }
};
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDDfk2mQIULmTxhwzxkO?p=preview)